# Laravel check if request came from browser or rest client (mobile app)

Tags: laravel

I am using `Laravel 5.1`

In my project there is a `service-based architecture` in `MVVM` pattern. Hence, all of the data return by the server is using api calls.

The same services are used by the client browsers as well as by mobile apps (i.e. we've created in `Android` and `iOS`) for `CRUD` operations.

I want to detect now if the request is came from any browser (including mobile browser too) or is called from any mobile device (i.e. using mobile app, NOT the mobile browser). Is there any way to differentiate it?

Setting custom header in requests (i.e. coming from mobile apps) can be a solution but I don't want to follow it if any solution is possible using laravel codes.

Comment: Use HTTP user agent. Just google it and you will come to know

Comment: @vikrammistry, here is the user agent of an android app I used to identify: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; Micromax A106 Build/KOT49H) , you cannot differentiate if it is browser or app.

Answer (score 0):

it working for me.
`
public function somethingfunc(Request $request)
      {
        $request->header('User-Agent')
        ....

`

Answer (score -1):

Presently there is no function to detect device type in Laravel 4, 5 and 5.2,
However, you can simply check if device mobile with this.

```
if( preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])){
   //hey I'm a mobile device
}
```

To detect other device features such as screen resolution, screen size, OS etc, you can try some of this Laravel Packages:

https://github.com/CodyPChristian/browscap-laravel

https://github.com/hisorange/browser-detect

Comment: It is not only detection of mobile browsers but the browsers (any OS like windows, mac, linux..). I simply want to differentiate if request is hit by browser or by app?

Comment: In this case the packages identifies the request has came from mobile but cannot differentiate that it has been sent from mobile browser or app. For example I received the request with user agent below from app: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; Micromax A106 Build/KOT49H) but the package is not able to identify if it is a device browser's call or is it from app.